# My URL isn't being rewritten using the WEB CONFIG

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Current URL:

> localhost:62859/review.aspx?c=football&t=Liverpool

The URL I'm trying to achieve

> localhost:62859/football/Liverpool

The code in web config I'm using to try and achieve this

```
<rule name="Rewrite Review">
  <match url="^review/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="?c={R:1}&amp;t={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

This just returns a 404 response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you understand what URL rewriting does? `localhost:62859/football/Liverpool` is what you should be showing to the user (i.e. outputting in your HTML); `localhost:62859/review.aspx?c=football&t=Liverpool` is what the server/application expects. Your `<match />` pattern should be attempting to match what the user sees (because that is what will get posted back to the server), and then the `<action />` should specify how to turn the matched text into what the server expects. Your `<action />` looks fine; your `<match />` needs work. That pattern doesn't correlate to the characters in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rule name="rewrite">
  <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/review.aspx?c={R:1}&amp;t={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Works.